# Connect from container to a service on the host (docker for mac)

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I have a somewhat complex situation and am probably out of luck here, but here's hoping. This is part of a large development project, so my options for what changes I can make are somewhat limited.

I have a virtual machine running a k8s cluster. That cluster has an http service that is exposed via ingress, and is available, on my local machine, at `develop.com`, via an `/etc/hosts` entry on the host mac.

I have a container, necessarily (see above) separate from the cluster, which needs access to this service. This container uses an env var, `SERVICE_HOST` to configure its requests.

What is the simplest way to provide a value that can be resolved by the standalone container to my cluster? Ideally, something other than `ngrok` which is simple, but is complicated by the fact that it's already in use in this setup to allow the cluster to reach the standalone container! I'd much prefer to make this work without premium features...

I'm aware of `--net=host` concept, but it doesn't work on an OSX host.